# I'm blind and need help with the commands for City of Hope Mush

Tags: accessibility, city-of-hope-mush

I'm blind and need some help on City of Hope Mush. Is there someone who can give me some advice? I am having trouble generating a sheet and I want to be a vampire. I use a screen reader and I don't know the commands for the game.

Comment: I am not familiar with that, but there is information about character creation on [the Character Generation wiki page](https://cityofhopemush.net/index.php/Character_Generation#Welcome). Among other things it suggests there is a channel called "new" and you can use the command "+request" followed by your request, which might help you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're already aware of this, but I'll add this here:

MUSHClient is a client developed for MUDs (and similar games) which has the capacity for accessibility functionality. It's also just a good client, I'm a sighted person and swore by it for the nearly two decades I played these games.

You can get instructions to make it work with screen readers at this link: [https://www.allinaccess.com/mc/#:~:text=Mushclient%20is%20a%20MUD%20client,(Multi%2Duser%20Dungeons)](https://www.allinaccess.com/mc/#:%7E:text=Mushclient%20is%20a%20MUD%20client,(Multi%2Duser%20Dungeons).)

While I've never played on City of Hope, it's of a generation of MUSHes that should be fully supported by MUSHClient.